# dual booting a laptop with uefi firmware

Tags: windows-8, bios, uefi, ubuntu-16.04

I've disabled secure boot and chosen CSM Boot (Compatibility Support Module) mode and after restarting my laptop I've installed ubuntu.

Now I'm getting the choice to select an OS, but I'm able to load into only Ubuntu. If I try to load into Windows 8 using windows boot load option, it asks me to insert windows installation disk and install windows.

Note: My laptop came with pre-installed windows 8 with uefi firmware.

Please provide me a solution so that I can use my windows along with ubuntu.

Comment: Why did you enable CSM if you want to dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu if Windows 8 is already installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: Don't disable the setting Windows was originally installed with, then proceed installing ubuntu that just works with anything?

Comment: I can't uninstall Ubuntu. Is there any way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to proceed, including a full re-installation of Ubuntu. The two easiest ways to fix your installation are:

- **Option 1: Use Boot Repair**

  1. Reconfigure your firmware to boot in EFI/UEFI mode (that is, *disable* the CSM).
  2. Prepare an Ubuntu emergency disk so that it can boot in EFI mode. (Note that a specialized disk that ships with Boot Repair is available; see the link in the next step for details.) This may require using specific tools or adjusting the options on whatever tool you used to create your Ubuntu installer. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html#creating-media) for details.
  3. Boot the Ubuntu emergency disk and run [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
  4. Shut down and reboot. With any luck, everything will work fine.
- **Option 2: Use rEFInd**

  1. Reconfigure your firmware to boot in EFI/UEFI mode (that is, *disable* the CSM).
  2. Disable Secure Boot in your firmware. (You can re-enable it later if you want, but you'll have to jump through some extra hoops.)
  3. Download the USB flash drive or CD-R image of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and write the image to a suitable medium.
  4. Boot with the rEFInd external medium. You should see a menu with both Windows and Ubuntu boot options.
  5. Boot to Ubuntu.
  6. Install rEFInd on the hard disk by installing the Debian package or PPA version.
  7. If you want to use Secure Boot, you'll need to install Shim or PreLoader and then re-enable Secure Boot in your firmware. See [rEFInd's Secure Boot documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) for details.
  8. Shut down and reboot. With any luck, everything will work fine.

The easiest approach, as both mirh and Ramhound commented, is to install Ubuntu in the same mode used by Windows. If you were following instructions you read online to enable the CSM, please contact the author of that page and ask that it be updated, since that advice was never good to begin with, and leads to continuing problems like yours.